# Checking user inputted URLs in Objective C/XCode 6 - NSRangeException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsrangeexception

G'day,

I'm attempting to check user-inputted URLs in a browser app. The aim is to add the http:// etc scheme if the user doesn't input it, and to assume they're after a Google search if they include any spaces within the text field.

I think I'm just about there but am crashing due to the following error whenever I type in something that isn't a complete URL and doesn't have spaces. Put simply,

- Inputting 'National Rugby League' will load Google correctly with that search term
- Inputting 'http://www.nrl.com.au' loads the NRL webpage correctly
- Inputting 'www.nrl.com.au' causes the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'**

I've looked at the following similar questions with no luck:

[How to validate an(sic) url on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone)

[Checking if a string is a url objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016957/checking-if-a-string-is-a-url-objective-c?lq=1)

[NSRange crashing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212371/nsrange-crashing-app)

This question is very similar to mine but wasn't quite answered:

[Correcting user submitted url in xcode objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349428/correcting-user-submitted-url-in-xcode-objective-c)

Please find my code below

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];

NSString *URLString = textField.text;

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

if (!URL.scheme) {

    NSRange urlSpace = [URLString rangeOfString:@" "];
    NSString *urlNoSpace = [URLString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:urlSpace withString:@"+"];

    if (urlSpace.location != NSNotFound) {
    // The user typed a space so we assume it's a search engine query
        URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", urlNoSpace]];
    } else {
    // The user didn't type http: or https: for the scheme
        URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URLString]];
    }
}

if (URL) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}

return NO;
```

}

Thank you for any help you can provide, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL doesn't have a space, then `urlSpace` will have a `location` of `NSNotFound` and a `length` of 0 (or is it -1?).

You need to check this before using the range to create `urlNoSpace`.

Since you really want to change all spaces why not simply do:

```
NSString *urlNoSpace = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

This fixes two problems: your crash and it replaces all spaces, not just the first one.

Comment: Thanks maddy! I had no idea about `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. If I don't use the range though, how can I find out whether or not the user entered a space into the text field?

Comment: Leave all your code as-is. Just change the one line I show in my answer.